# Where is $.destroyTopic defined?

Tags: jquery, struts2, publish-subscribe

Our Struts 2 application makes use of `destroyTopic` for pub/sub messaging.

A couple of years ago, a now-retired coworker integrated javaMelody into our application for monitoring.  My task is to remove it.  While this should be as simple as removing javaMelody from the web.xml and pom.xml, it is not.  During the course of the application's evolution, dependencies on what javaMelody includes were unknowingly created.

What seems to be the last dependency is the definition of `jQuery.destroyTopic()`.  I can not, however, seem to find where it is defined and what JavaScript library must be included to provide the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further info, I'd assume it's the [Struts 2 jQuery plugin](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki):

https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/blob/9eea410ea430300611ba34d96d588c299c28fc05/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.js#L81

That said, it's not directly related to JavaMelody (on cursory inspection).

Comment: That's what I would think also, but it is no where to be found.

Comment: @dacracot Seems unlikely, but ok.